# Как перенести готовый блок от одной ячейки к другой jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такой вопрос: Есть верстка и стили и блок созданный на jQuery - В первом ячейки, Надо этот же блок перенести на следующий Помогите пожалуйста

```js
$(function() {

  var newTasks = [];

  // Создания ТАССКОВ

  function addTaskToDOM(task, progress) {
    var blocks = $('<div class="blocks"></div>')
    var newSpan = $('<span>x</span>').addClass('exit');
    var newTitle = $('<h1 id="newTitle"></h1>').text(task);
    var newButton = $('<button>').addClass('newBtn').text('In Progress >>>');

    blocks.append(newSpan, newTitle, newButton);

    $('.task-' + progress).append(blocks);


  };

  // Сохранение в LOCALSTORAGE

  function saveTaskToLocal(arr, task, localKey) {
    arr.push(task);

    var arrStr = JSON.stringify(arr);

    localStorage.setItem(localKey, arrStr);
  };

  // Получение Элементов от LocalStorage
  function getTasksFromLocalstorage(arr, progress, localKey) {
    arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localKey)) || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      addTaskToDOM(arr[1], progress);
    }
  }



  // Действие на кнопку Add
  $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var task = $('#taskName').val();

    addTaskToDOM(task, 'new');

    saveTaskToLocal(newTasks, task, 'new');


  });


  getTasksFromLocalstorage(newTasks, 'new', 'new');



  // Progress

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: url(../img/gif.gif) */
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  padding: .5rem;
  background: #ccc;
}

.add-task {
  display: flex;
}

.task-name {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.btn-add {
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task-list {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.task-body {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.newBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black;
}

.exit {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <form class="add-task">
        <input type="text" class="task-name" id="taskName" placeholder="Enter task name" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-add">Add</button>
      </form>
    </header>

    <div class="task-list">
      <div class="task-item">
        <h3 class="task-title">To DO</h3>
        <div class="task-body task-new"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="task-item">
        <h3 class="task-title">In progress</h3>
        <div class="task-body task-progress"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="task-item">
        <h3 class="task-title">Done</h3>
        <div class="task-body task-done"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что скопировать, куда скопировать, когда скопировать, что значит скопировать? Ну и с localStorage приведённый Вами пример здесь в "песочнице" работать не будет, т.к. `Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.`, т.е. домен "песочницы" отличается от текущего. Помимо это постарайтесь в Вашем примере удалить всё, что не относится к задаче. Иначе количество желающих в нём разобраться будет стремиться к нулю.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
        var newTasks = [];
        const $taskList = $(".task-list");
        const $tasksInProgress = $(".task-progress");

        // Создания ТАССКОВ

        function addTaskToDOM(task, progress) {
          var blocks = $('<div class="blocks"></div>');
          var newSpan = $("<span>x</span>").addClass("exit");
          var newTitle = $('<h1 id="newTitle"></h1>').text(task);
          var newButton = $("<button>")
            .addClass("newBtn")
            .text("In Progress >>>");

          blocks.append(newSpan, newTitle, newButton);

          $(".task-" + progress).append(blocks);
        }

        // Сохранение в LOCALSTORAGE

        function saveTaskToLocal(arr, task, localKey) {
          arr.push(task);

          var arrStr = JSON.stringify(arr);

          localStorage.setItem(localKey, arrStr);
        }

        // Получение Элементов от LocalStorage
        function getTasksFromLocalstorage(arr, progress, localKey) {
          arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localKey)) || [];

          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            addTaskToDOM(arr[1], progress);
          }
        }

        // Действие на кнопку Add
        $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var task = $("#taskName").val();

          addTaskToDOM(task, "new");

          saveTaskToLocal(newTasks, task, "new");
        });

        getTasksFromLocalstorage(newTasks, "new", "new");

        // Progress

        $taskList.on("click", ".newBtn", function() {
          const $blocks = $(this).parents(".blocks");
          $tasksInProgress.append($blocks);
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Добавил что бы по нажатию на кнопку In progress блок перемещался в таски in progress